# Does DC energy propagation speed depend on current? What about AC?

Tags: ac, dc, energy

I understand that the speed at which energy propagates from the source to the load is much faster than the drift velocity and current of the electrons in a wire. I am wondering if the magnitude of the current in a wire will affect how long it takes for the energy to actually reach the destination?

Obviously, the energy from the source doesn't reach the load instantaneously so I am wondering if the time it takes for the energy to actually travel to the load is dependent on the magnitude of the current.

I'm guessing that if the current is larger then the energy transferred between electrons will happen faster and therefore the energy will reach the load faster compared to a small current? Is this effect negligible?

I know for AC signals, the speed at which the wave travels depends on the medium (would travel at the speed of light in a vacuum since it is an EM wave), is the speed of the wave also affected by the current in AC?

Comment: A true DC (0 Hz) signal is unchanging and eternal.  It has always existed and always will.  It carries no information and has no motion, so how would you measure a "speed"?  Any signal or edge you add to it transforms it into a very low frequency but not DC signal, in which case you can use normal AC equations.

Comment: @user1850479 So, your conclusion, DC can not transfrer energy?

Comment: @user263983 DC can transfer energy. But energy is not information. I'm simplifying more than I should, but information is more in the 'change of energy' than in the 'energy itself'.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if the magnitude of the current in a wire will affect
> how long it takes for the energy to actually reach the destination?

No, but the inductance of the wire will slow the propagation of electric fields\current through the wire. If you have 1Amp or 2Amps the speed at which the current increases is the same.

> I'm guessing that if the current is larger then the energy transferred
> between electrons will happen faster and therefore the energy will
> reach the load faster compared to a small current? Is this effect
> negligible?

If you have an R L circuit (which is essentially what wire is) then the time will be the same if you increase the voltage (which also increases the current). Double the current or voltage and the load will see the same rise time.

> I know for AC signals, the speed at which the wave travels depends on
> the medium (would travel at the speed of light in a vacuum since it is
> an EM wave), is the speed of the wave also affected by the current in
> AC?

Yes, if the wire has inductance and resistance (which every wire does) then it also slows down AC.

Answer (score 0):

> *Obviously, the energy from the source doesn't reach the load
> instantaneously so I am wondering if the time it takes for the energy
> to actually travel to the load is dependent on the magnitude of the
> current.*

Short answer is no, it's not dependent on the magnitude of the current. It's wholly dependent on the transmission line characteristics of the forward and return wires that feed your load. Those wires (and their respective inductance and capacitance per metre) define the speed in which current and voltage waves travel down the wire-pair.

Just as the speed of light (also an electromagnetic wave) is defined by the properties of free space (\$\mu_0\$ and \$\epsilon_0\$), the wires have an equivalent set of values that reshape the speed in which electromagnetic waves travel down the wire.

> *I'm guessing that if the current is larger then the energy transferred
> between electrons will happen faster and therefore the energy will
> reach the load faster compared to a small current? Is this effect
> negligible?*

The effect is negligible; in fact, the effect doesn't exist as far as I know but, maybe some PhD physicist somewhere might have found some obscure relationship that I'm currently unaware of.